# When I try to access a website without www I get access denied

Tags: apache-2.2, cakephp

I have an apache web server on a debian machine. I'm using virtualmin to administer virtual hosts. I have two sites on this server right now, when I try to access one site without the www in the URL I get an access denied. The other site is fine. The site with the problem is a cakephp app and has the following .htaccess file in the public_html folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Below is the directives for the problem domain.

```
SuexecUserGroup "#1001" "#1001"
ServerName mydomain.net
ServerAlias www.mydomain.net
ServerAlias webmail.mydomain.net
ServerAlias admin.mydomain.net
DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.net_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.net_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mydomain/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/mydomain/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/mydomain/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/mydomain/cgi-bin>
allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.mydomain.net
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mydomain.net:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.mydomain.net
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mydomain.net:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
IPCCommTimeout 31
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "mydomain.net statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/mydomain/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
```

Comment: What are the apache error logs telling you about the problem? Have you checked directory permissions? What is the difference to your working configuration?

Comment: What happens if you go to http://mydomain.net/index.php (or other existing page)? Does it work?

Comment: cant find entry in error logs, and when i look for index.php it says not found. Also the config is identical to the working host.

Comment: The error log should be at `/var/log/httpd/error_log` under Virtualmin

Comment: not updating any logs. tried accessing last modified files.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you exchange ServerName with ServerAlias?

```
ServerName www.mydomain.net
ServerAlias mydomain.net
```

Then try to add another fake virtual domain.

Comment: first step doesnt make a difference. I was thinking of adding another virtual domain, but wondering if there was a less messy option.